# React check children input field value

Tags: reactjs

I have a child input component. How to check each `input` field value from parent when click button?  https://jsfiddle.net/sj83cL4a/

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      inputvalue : ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="hello">
        <Input 
          placeholder="Title 1" />
        <br/>
        <Input placeholder="Title 2" />
        <br/>
        <Input placeholder="Title 3" />
        <br/>
        <Input placeholder="Title 4" />
        <br/>
        <button>Get value</button>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Input extends React.Component  { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      inputvalue: ''
    }
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      inputvalue: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input 
        type="text" 
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder} 
        value={this.state.inputvalue} 
        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        />
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sj83cL4a/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to get values on button click you need to identify each input and set them in state, so we will use [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

```
<Input onChangeOfInput={this.onChangeOfInput} placeholder="Title 1" name="Title1" />
<br/>
<Input placeholder="Title 2" name="Title2" onChangeOfInput={this.onChangeOfInput} />
<br/>
<Input placeholder="Title 3" name="Title3" onChangeOfInput={this.onChangeOfInput}/>
<br/>
<Input placeholder="Title 4" name="Title4" onChangeOfInput={this.onChangeOfInput}/>
<br/>
<button onClick={this.getValues}>Get value</button>
```

here name is unique key

add one function to parent

```
  onChangeOfInput =(name,value) =>{
    this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
  }
```

callback from the child

```
handleChange(e) {      
        this.setState({
            inputvalue: e.target.value
        });
       this.props.onChangeOfInput(this.props.name,e.target.value)
}
```

and use the state when you want

```
 getValues = () =>{
    console.log(this.state);
  }
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s9ej6gnz/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `updateInputValue` with `setState` to specific `Input` child, then call in updating:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
      input1: null,
      input2: null,
      input3: null,
      input4: null
  }
 }
  
  updateInputValue(target, val) {
    this.setState({[target]: val})
  }
  
 render() {
  return (
   <div className="hello">
      <Input name="input1" updateInputValue={this.updateInputValue.bind(this)}
      placeholder="Title 1" />
      <br/>
      <Input name="input2" updateInputValue={this.updateInputValue.bind(this)} placeholder="Title 2" />
      <br/>
      <Input name="input3" updateInputValue={this.updateInputValue.bind(this)} placeholder="Title 3" />
      <br/>
      <Input name="input4" updateInputValue={this.updateInputValue.bind(this)} placeholder="Title 4" />
      <br/>
      <button>Get value</button>
      <div>{this.state.input1}</div>        
      <div>{this.state.input2}</div>
      <div>{this.state.input3}</div>
      <div>{this.state.input4}</div>
   </div>
    )
  }
}
  
class Input extends React.Component  { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      inputvalue: ''
    }
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      inputvalue: e.target.value
    })
    this.props.updateInputValue(this.props.name, e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input 
      type="text" 
      placeholder={this.props.placeholder} 
      value={this.state.inputvalue} 
      onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
      />
    )
  }
}
    
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```